# Using two different RDD's in a function for calculation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have created a function that takes two RDD's that represent different sets. These RDD's are in no way guaranteed to be the same size (and 99% of the time won't be anyways). I ideally want to partition both the RDD's the same number of times (if enough can even be created), and then pass them so the function can be called 'partition number' of times in parallel. Is there syntax to specific this?

Edit: Also I just wanted to quickly change the specification. Since one RDD is guaranteed to be much larger than the other, I want one of the RDD's to be partitioned accordingly (e.g. 16 times). However, for the other RDD, I want it to be partitioned only once, so the same one, and all of it, is passed to each of the functions running in parallel.

Comment: It is not clear what you really want here. How would you use RDDs in this function?

Comment: What I'm trying to actually do is more complicated, but essentially I'll want to apply a function to calculate statistical measures across the RDD's in each partition. But essentially, the main point is I need both RDD's, and somehow need the operation to be performed in parallel.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do?